# count of items from another table for each row in table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a list of user-profiles when I have this query. **I want to retrieve nr of followers for each (every) user**, but I only get one row result from query (there are a lot of users)

```
$this->db->select('up.name, up.id, up.image, up.name_id, up.created, COUNT(followers.user_id) as followed_by_count');
$this->db->join('user_profiles up', 'u.id = up.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('followers', 'up.user_id = followers.user_id', 'left');

//Something like this? (It doesn't work)
//$this->db->group_by('COUNT(followers.user_id) as followed_by_count'); 
//When tried this I get:
//"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  
//MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as followed_by_count"

$this->db->order_by('up.created', 'DESC');
```

I guess I should use `group by` in some way? The query works when not using followers-table. It also works when not using group_by but I obviously don't get the count(s) I want then.

Comment: You have to use `group by` clause

Comment: @Sadikhasan - what's wrong with my group_by then? (See comments in code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$this->db->group_by('COUNT(followers.user_id) as followed_by_count');
```

To

```
$this->db->group_by('u.id');
```

Note : This code given as per your given code and assume that your code is syntactically right.

Comment: Have you solve your problem? then accept answer for future use

Comment: Yes. It solved my problem! I'm going to accept as soon as I'm allowed to :-)(I have to wait about 5min)